# PHP Sort string value range array in numeric Order

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, numeric

I have an array of range type values 257-1024, 1-256, 1025-2056. All these values are dynamically generated and positioned randomed. Before making an output I have to sort them in a numeric ASC order. Using sort or natsort function is giving the output as 1-256,1025-2056, 257-1024 as php recognise it as string. Is there a built in function with which this can be sorted/arranged in numeric range order i.e 1-256, 257-1024, 1025-2056

Comment: you can create your own sorting function using php usort
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [natsort() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)  here.

```
$array = array("257-1024", "1-256", "1025-2056");

$a = natsort($array);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($array);

echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
   [1] => 1-256
   [0] => 257-1024
   [2] => 1025-2056
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below using usort().

```
$array = ['257-1024', '1025-2056', '1-256'];
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ((int)explode('-', $a)[1] < (int)explode('-', $b)[0]) ? -1 : 1;
});
print_r($array);
```

Output is below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-256
    [1] => 257-1024
    [2] => 1025-2056
)
```